# Autoformat input field

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript, which I supposed to format phone number to +1 (222) 555 22-22, but for some reason it stops to work just on first number.. Can you elaborate what's I'm doing wrong?

```js
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,1})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[3] ? x[1] : '+' + x[1] + '(' + x[2] + ') ' + x[3] + (x[4] ? '-' + x[4] : '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="+1 (222) 444-5555"/>
```

Comment: Use the event `blur` instead of `input`. Input is validating each type the value changes, where as blur changes it once the user has the left the field.

Comment: but the thing is, i want to display format while input being filled. Also, I've noticed that I made a mistake instead of  !x[2] ? x[1] i wrote  !x[3] ? x[1] - but now I have another problem - I could delete only this part of number "555 22-22"

Comment: Hello. Do you have to use regex? I think you can do this easier with a plugin.

Comment: Yeah, I've used it for bit